# How to get Jest to have coverage for export only lines?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, sonarqube, ts-jest, sonarcloud

I have an `index.ts` top file in an NPM library which has only export statements.

i.e.:

```
export * from "./foo"
export * from "./bar"
```

SonarCloud is showing those lines as not covered, as it is expected that those should have no tests. I know we can live with the missing coverage but it is somehow annoying.

I know I could also ignore the file, but then I would need to do the same for every file with a similar purpose that group and export components down inside the library.

Is there any best practice or configuration I can use to overcome that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research I found an option that is aligned with what I was looking for.

### Mocha

This is inspired by MaterialUI repo which uses `mocha` with `chai`:

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import * as MyLib from './index';

describe('MyLib', () => {
  it('should have exports', () => {
    expect(typeof MyLib).to.equal('object');
  });

  it('should not have undefined exports', () => {
    Object.keys(MyLib).forEach((exportKey) =>
      expect(Boolean(MyLib[exportKey])).to.equal(true),
    );
  });
});
```

source: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui/src/index.test.js

### JEST

As we use JEST in my project we had to convert it:

```
import * as MyLib from './index';

describe('MyLib', () => {
  it('should have exports', () => {
    expect(MyLib).toEqual(expect.any(Object));
  });

  it('should not have undefined exports', () => {
    for (const k of Object.keys(MyLib))
      expect(MyLib).not.toHaveProperty(k, undefined);
  });
});
```

Comment: You have resolved such a headache for me. Adding exports to my library caused test coverage to fail, and jest was unable to indicate which specific lines were uncovered! For some reason this solves the issue. I'd love to see an edit from anyone who understands *why* this solves the issue. I've also made a small edit to improve the use of `jest`!

Comment: @GershomMaes thank you for the edit. I do understand why the coverage would be lower, but not why it would fail. The test runner will evaluate the lines executed, but files containing only imports don’t have their own unit test files as there is nothing really to test. This code makes the runner pass by those lines/files and consider them as tested.

Comment: my edit leaves the pass/fail logic completely unchanged, but it simply gives some nicer feedback in case the expectations fail! For example jest will indicate the specific key and value which are set to `undefined`